# Expected an identifier and instead saw '0'

Tags: javascript, jslint

How would this jslint error be fixed in here? https://jsfiddle.net/cfv2g1ho/

> [JSLint was unable to finish] Expected an identifier and instead saw
> '0'.

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    let playerVarsList = {
        0: {
            playerVars: {
                playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
            }
        },
        1: {
            playerVars: {
                listType: "playlist",
                list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
            }
        }
    }
    //to add the player to all the play buttons
    const totalP = document.querySelectorAll('[data-container="play1"]').length;

    //looping over all the play buttons and adding player to that
    for (let i = 0; i < totalP; i++) {
        players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i] || {}));
    }
    players.add(".playInitial", {});

}
```

Comment: If you already know why this error happens, what keeps you from resolving it?

Comment: You can change the code with any text editor. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0` is not a valid identifier, `"0"` is however. But you're handling your object as an array - so why aren't you using an array instead of an object?

```js
    let playerVarsList = [
        {
            playerVars: {
                playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
            }
        },
        {
            playerVars: {
                listType: "playlist",
                list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
            }
        }
    ]
```

If you do have some reason to absolutely use an object, however:

```js
    let playerVarsList = {
        "0": {
            playerVars: {
                playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            playerVars: {
                listType: "playlist",
                list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
            }
        }
    }
```

Be careful with using [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) when mixing numbers and strings, e.g. `playerVarsList[i]` won't work if strict mode is enabled.

Comment: Use double quotes, not single quotes. How exactly do I do that here? totalPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-container="play1"]').length;

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(\`[data-container="play1"]\`)` or `document.querySelectorAll("[data-container=\"play1\"]")`

Comment: Code doesn't work now: playerVarsList[i] https://jsfiddle.net/aegkjpf1/ What do I do?

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < totalP; i++)`... `totalP` is not a number, it's a DOM element collection (array like)... you should use `totalP.length`.